# aws credentials error could not load credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have job that checking aws ec2 instances every 5 minutes, once in 5-6 days the job failed with error : aws credentials error could not load credentials but in the next run its working well.
Someone have any idea ?

Comment: Where is the code running -- on your own computer, or on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: on jenkins slave on aws ec2 instance

Comment: Software running on an Amazon EC2 instance usually obtain AWS credentials via an IAM Role that is assigned to the instance. The EC2 metadata service then uses this IAM Role to provide temporary credentials to the instance. These credentials typically expire after about 6 hours and are automatically refreshed. It might be that _something_ in your system is caching credentials and they are expiring before being refreshed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, do you know if it possible to clear these cash ?

Comment: It all depends on where it is being kept! Based on the information you have provided, no.

Comment: Solved the issue was old aws CLI version